# FFMPEG audio distorted after convertion using fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I am trying to convert the following file to wav audio using FFMPEG

[Input File](https://github.com/cleancoder7/FFmpeg-Playground/blob/master/audio_file.mp4?raw=true)

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
ffmpeg()
        .input('https://github.com/cleancoder7/FFmpeg-Playground/blob/master/audio_file.mp4?raw=true')
        .noVideo()
        .format('wav')
        .outputOptions('-ar 16000')
        .outputOptions('-ac 1')
        .on('start', commandLine => console.log(`Spawned Ffmpeg with command: ${commandLine}`))
        .on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
        })
        .on('end', function () {
            console.log('Processing finished !');
        })
        .save('converted_out.wav');
```

But i am getting distorted audio in the output file. What am i missing ??

Comment: The `audio_file.mp4` input file also sounds distorted.

Comment: @llogan, but the converted audio became this,

https://github.com/cleancoder7/FFmpeg-Playground/blob/master/converted_out.wav?raw=true

Comment: How was `audio_file.mp4` created?